# couchdb Map View performace very slow

Tags: couchdb

I am using couchDb.

In CouchDB I have inserted 1000 documents.
When I get the data from the database it takes 4 seconds to retrieve the 1000 data. How to reduce the time taken when retrieving data from the database?

```
{
 {
    "_id": "_design/syncStat",
    "language": "javascript",
    "views": {
        "syncStat": {
            "map": "function(doc) {\
               emit(doc.order_placed_on, null)
               }"
              }
             }
 }
}
```

When I retrieve the data I am using this url: http://localhost:5984/order_info/_design/syncStat/_view/syncStat

If I have 1000 records it takes 4 seconds to return the results. It's very slow, how to improve this situation?

Comment: The view looks good and 4s is way beyond what should occur as request-time. Large documents can cause performance degradation. If you have large documents (in the order of MBytes) this could be an issue...

Comment: What if you split your query into multiple one? Is it faster? Maybe the problem is not with CouchDB but how you use it. Query huge chunk of data through HTTP can be very slow.

Comment: I expect 4 seconds would be normal if you had just inserted the 1000 docs and this is the first time you call the view. After the view is done indexing the first time, however it should return nearly instantaneously. Could the 4 seconds be the "first index" time or just your HTTP speed downloading the entire view output?